# Global.asax not firing on IIS 8.5

Tags: global-asax, iis-8

The  Global.asax(.cs) Application_BeginRequest fires on Cassini and IIS 7.5 (Windows 7) but not on IIS 8.5 (Windows Server 2012).

I've researched this in every way possible, changed settings both in web.config and IIS Manager and compared settings between 7.5 and 8.5.  There doesn't seem to be much documentation on IIS 8.5 at this level.

The code is a simple Context.RewritePath call on selected urls.

Any suggestions on what to try or where to look for answers?

Comment: You have to deploy as a web site or an application under a web site. It won't work if deployed as a virtual directory or physical directory.

Comment: It is deployed as a site.  The URL's being being trapped / rewritten are in the root directory.

Comment: @jbecker, I'm facing the same issue. I have deployed the web application as an application under a website on IIS 8.5. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @jbecker: hello, did you find any solution? please share with us, i am heading with same issue. thanks

Comment: I found that this was better handled in a VirtualPrivatePath, which has its own set of issues.  Neither are widely used so there's not a lot of info coming from the community.  Now the only issue is caching.